# How to deploy a Static website project with bun.lockb to Github Pages?

Tags: npm, github-pages, package.json, bun

I have a vite-react static page project, where I have exclusively used bun to install packages and for building the project.That's the reason it does not have package-json.lock instead it has bun.lockb.

Now I am trying to deploy this project into Github pages. I am using the template yml provided by [Vite official documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy#:%7E:text=name%3A%20Deploy%20static%20content%20to%20Pages).

This is the error I see in the GitHub deployment log. I understand that this is because my project does not have package-json.lock.

[image: Github Deployment error]

> Error: Dependencies lock file is not found in /home/runner/work/rolling/rolling. Supported file patterns: package-lock.json,npm-shrinkwrap.json,yarn.lock

Can I configure the deployment anywhere in Github, for it to understand that it has to look at bun.lockb instead of package-json.lock?

If this is not possible, the only other way to solve it would be to just use both npm and bun in the project so that npm generates the package-json.lock file. or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You'll want to use a Bun setup instead of Node.js. See https://bun.sh/guides/runtime/cicd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil). I figured out how to use Github Pages with bun. These are the changes that the project needed.

Below are the changes I made. Left part of image is the yml from [vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy#:%7E:text=name%3A%20Deploy%20static%20content%20to%20Pages:%7E:text=%23%20Simple%20workflow%20for%20deploying%20static%20content%20to%20GitHub%20Pages), right is the changes I made for bun.

[Changes I made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0QG7.png)
[image: Changes I madee]